# Space in file name pathways

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am working for an organization that uses Google Drive File Stream for GIS data storage (ArcGIS Desktop). As a result, the root folder for all of the GIS files begins with "G:\Shared drives", which has a space in it. We are unable to change this name to eliminate the space. I know that GIS does not like spaces in file name pathways when doing analysis. Is there any solution to this? Every GIS data file we have will start with this. How much of a problem will this cause?

Comment: In my experience, spaces in file names cause problems, not spaces in directory paths.

Comment: I've done testing that shows that both shapefile and file geodatabase access to network (CIFS and NFS) data volumes takes roughly twice as long as local disk processing, even on an ideal network with two hosts. It's not ideal to have spaces in all fully-qualified paths, but it's not the spaces that could hurt you so much as high latency on disk access. It's probably worth doing your own test of local vs shared storage, to see if "copy data locally" and "upload to the shared drive" should be prepended and postpended (respectively) to your task procedures.

Comment: Indeed - I always copied local, did whatever was required, and then copied back.  GIS over network was never ideal, and I image GIS into GDFS is likely worse